# Exponentiation by squaring in x64 Linux Assembly

Tags: algorithm, mathematics, linux, assembly, nasm

I am learning some assembly for a compiler project I am working on and I have come across the Exponentiation by Squaring algorithm when it came to calculating x ^ n. To get a grasp on how the algorithm works before I add the operation to my code generation, I have written it out to see if it works.

Is my code optimum? and can it be improved on (such as reducing the number of line needed and efficiency?)

I am assembling with nasm and I am running on x86_64 linux

```
;   Function exp_by_squaring_iterative(x, n)
_ipow:
   ; set the x and y values
   mov r8, 50 ; x
   mov r9, 10 ; n

   ; check if n is 1
   cmp r9, 1         ; compare n with 1
   je _equalsOne     ; goto equalsone if n is 1
   jne _notEqualsOne ; goto noequalsone if n is not 1

; return 1
_equalsOne:
   mov rax, r8 
   ret         ; if n equals 1 return x

;     if n < 0 then
_notEqualsOne:
   cmp r9, 0       ; compare n with 0
   jl _lessthan    ; goto lessthan zero if x is less than zero
   jnl _equalszero ; goto equalszero if n is equal to zero

_lessthan:
;       x := 1 / x;
;       n := -n;
   xor rdx, rdx ; zero rdx
   mov rax, 1  ; move 1 to rax
   div r8      ; divide 1 / x
   mov r8, rax ; move x back to r8
   not r9      ; revers ns bits
   
;     if n = 0 then return 1
_equalszero:   
   cmp r9, 0   ; compare n with zero
   je _ezero   ; go to ezero if n equals zero
   jne _nzero  ; go to nzero if n is not zero

_ezero: ; return 1
   mov rax, 1  ; set rax as 1 
   ret         ; return 1 if n is 0

;     y := 1;
_nzero:
   mov r10, 1 ; set r10 as 1, y

_loop1:
   mov rax, r9  ; move n to rax
   test al, 1   ; check if n is an odd number by testing the low bit 
   jz  _even    ; jump if even = lowest bit clear = zero
   jnz _odd     ; jump if odd  = lowest bit set
   
;       if n is even then 
_even:
;         x := x * x;
   mov rax, r8 ; move x to rax
   mul rax     ; multiply x by itself
   mov r8, rax ; move x back to r8

;         n := n / 2;
   mov rbx, 2  ; 2 to rbx
   mov rax, r9 ; move n to rax
   div rbx     ; divide n by 2
   mov r9, rax ; move n back

   jmp _condition ; jump over odd since if even, was processed

; n is an odd number
_odd:
;         y := x * y;
   mov rax, r10 ; move y to rax
   mul r8   ; multiply y by x
   mov r10, rax ; move y back to r10

;         x := x * x;
   mov rax, r8 ; mov x to rax
   mul rax  ; multiply x by itself 
   mov r8, rax ; mov x back to r10

;         n := (n – 1) / 2;
   mov rax, r9 ; mov n to rax
   sub rax, 1  ; minus 1 from n
   mov rbx, 2  ; set rbx as 2
   div rbx     ; divide n by 2
   mov r9, rax ; move n back to rax

;     while n > 1 do
_condition:
   cmp r9, 1   ; compare r9 with 1
   jg _loop1   ; if 1 is greater than 1 then loop

;     return x * y
   mov rax, r8 ; move x to rax
   mul r10     ; multiple x and y
   ret         ; return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Testing for `n == 1` before handling a negative `n` seems like a bug. Consider what would have happen with `n == -1`:

  1. `n` is not `1`. Branch to `_notEqualsOne`.
  2. `n` is less than `0`. Branch to `_lessthan`. Now `n` becomes `1`.
  3. The code falls through all the way to `_loop1`.
  4. `n` is odd. Branch to `_odd`.
  5. `y` := x * y`;` x := x * x`;` n := 0`
  6. `_condition` fails; fall through the `return x * y`.

  Now, this is bad: we are returning an inversed *cube* of the original `x`.

  Postpone equality for `1` testing until the negative case is handled.
- Eliminate `_equalsOne` label:

  ```
    cmp r9, 1
    jne _notEqualsOne

    mov rax, r8
    ret

  _notEqualsOne:
  ```
- `cmp r9, 0` is executed twice. This is redundant (keep in mind that `jne` does not affect the flags):

  ```
    cmp r9, 0
    jne _notZero
    ; next two lines is what your code does at _ezero
    mov rax, 1
    ret

  _notZero:
    jnl _positive
    ; handle a negative case here:
    ; x := 1/x
    ; n := -n
    ; and proceed with the _positive case
    ....

  _positive:
    ; A regular case. n > 1 is guaranteed.
  ```
- Again, `_even` and `_odd` lead to some code duplication.  `x := x * x` and `n := n/2` are spelled out in both branches. Consider

  ```
    test al, 1
    jz _even

    ; n is odd here
    ; y := x * y
    ; n := n - 1

  _even:
    ; x := x * x
    ; n := n / 2
  ```
- Division by 2 is better be a right shift. One instruction versus four; a definite win.
- `while n > 1` style loop looks more natural than `do ... while n > 1`.

Comment: I have to disagree with that last point. Rather, all loops should have the branch on the bottom, to avoid having an extra jump in the loop. A literal `while` loop in assembly just makes the code look like it naively transcribed from higher level code.

Comment: @harold readability is more important than a tiny performance increase when this code is clearly not optimized to squeeze out performance.

Comment: @qwr it's not even more readable. Do-loops are *the most standard* pattern.

Answer (score 1):

## Handling `n < 0`

The computation is entirely integer-based. When `x := 1 / x` is computed, that means the new `x` is *usually zero*, though if `x` was 1 to begin with then the new `x` is still 1.

As it currently is, with an integer computation, handling negative `n` makes very little sense. It almost never gives a useful result. It makes more sense to just not handle that case at all - of course this saves code.

## There are more ways to multiply than `mul`

> ```
> ;         x := x * x;
>    mov rax, r8 ; move x to rax
>    mul rax     ; multiply x by itself
>    mov r8, rax ; move x back to r8
> ```

Unless you need the upper 64 bits of the 128 bit product, it is easier and more appropriate to use the 2-operand or 3-operand form (whichever applies) of `imul`. `imul` is described in the manual as a signed multiplication, but that only matters for "upper half" which is ignored in most cases. See for example [Why is imul used for multiplying unsigned numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607/555045).

So this code can be:

```
imul r8, r8
```

## Loading small constants into 64bit registers

`mov rax, 1` is actually not the best way to set `rax` to 1, the best way is `mov eax, 1`.

If the assembler honours the program text, `mov rax, 1` would be encoded as `48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00`, using a REX.W prefix and the C7-group `mov`. `mov eax, 1` does exactly the same thing (writes to 32bit registers are zero-extended) but can be encoded as `b8 01 00 00 00`, saving two bytes (a byte from REX prefix, and an extra byte because the B8-group `mov` can be used).

Saving 2 bytes is not critial, but all else being equal, smaller code is better (faster to fetch, less pressure on code cache).

## Comparing a register to zero

`cmp r9, 0` is an obvious way to do it, but `test r9, r9` saves a byte.